# DISTINCT is not working properly in left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `StockIn` and `StockOut`.

`StockIn` table has an Id number for the product, this Id number is unique in the `StockIn` table, where else this Id number will be duplicated in `StockOut` table as many time the stock will be sold out.

Now I want to create a view to find the stock in hand where `StockIn.Id` = `StockOut.Id`. So far I manage to query and it is giving the result but it fails when there are multiple order in the `StockOut` table of the same product, because of the duplicate Id number.

Below is my query:

```
select DISTINCT
  i.Id, 
  i.AssetsName, 
  i.Rate,
  i.Qty,
  So.QtyOut,  
   Balance =  sum( COALESCE(i.Qty,0)- COALESCE(so.QtyOut,0)) OVER(PARTITION BY i.id)
  from  dbo.StockIn i 
  LEFT Join  StockOut So
    on   i.Id =   So.Id
GO
```

Comment: could you please provide your expected output

Comment: Sample queries and data please wth expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple GROUP BY with normal SUM's should do.

```
SELECT
 si.Id, 
 si.AssetsName, 
 si.Rate,
 si.Qty,
 SUM(so.QtyOut) AS QtyOut,  
 COALESCE(si.Qty, 0) - SUM(so.QtyOut) AS Balance
FROM dbo.StockIn si 
LEFT JOIN dbo.StockOut so ON so.Id = si.Id
GROUP BY si.Id, si.AssetsName, si.Rate, si.Qty;
```

Comment: @ Lukstorms, like a charm so perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off collapsing your stock out to single row before you join

Remove the distinct - it doesn't help and isn't needed

```
select 
  id, 
  si.qtyin - so.qtyout as balance
from
  stockin si
  left join
  (select id, sum (qtyout) as qtyout from stockout group by id) so 
  on so.id = si.id
```

That means your joins will only ever be 1:0 (if no sales) or 1:1 (all sales summed before join)

What happens when you order more stuff? If you create another stockin record with the same ID then the same problem will happen for products that have been re-stocked. Use the same technique to collapse stockin to a single row before you join:

```
select 
  id, 
  si.qtyin - so.qtyout as balance
from
  (Select id, sum(qtyin) as qtyin stockin group by id) si
  left join
  (select id, sum (qtyout) as qtyout from stockout group by id) so 
  on so.id = si.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select 
  i.Id, 
  i.AssetsName, 
  i.Rate,
  i.Qty,
  sum( COALESCE(i.Qty,0)- COALESCE((Select Qtyout from StockIn Where StockIn.Id=StockOut.Id),0)) OVER(PARTITION BY i.id) as Balance
  from  dbo.StockIn i 
  group by Id,AssetsName,Rate,Qty
```

Comment: Group by already makes it unique. No need for distinct if there is a group by.